# df.reset not fully working need to skip the first row or find another function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following my previous question and @jezrael answer I still need some help with the following line of code:

df = df.reset_index().melt('index', var_name='cols',  value_name='vals')
When I apply it to the following df

subject    A1    A2    A3    A4    A5  ...    O1    O2    O3    O4    O5    O6

0    S001  24.0  25.0  25.0  15.0   6.0  ...  19.0  22.0  27.0  14.0  27.0  25.0

1    S002  30.0  22.0  27.0  22.0  18.0  ...  27.0  17.0  22.0  23.0  28.0  28.0

2    S003  26.0  21.0  21.0  19.0  16.0  ...  21.0   7.0  19.0  24.0  21.0  27.0

3    S004  24.0  16.0  24.0  22.0  17.0  ...  27.0   7.0  26.0  25.0  18.0  27.0

4    S005  18.0  18.0  21.0  13.0  14.0  ...  22.0  18.0  20.0  10.0  25.0  23.0

I obtain:
index     cols  vals

0        0  subject  S001

1        1  subject  S002

2        2  subject  S003

3        3  subject  S004

4        4  subject  S005

..     ...      ...   ...

150      0       O6    25

151      1       O6    28

152      2       O6    27

153      3       O6    27

154      4       O6    23

How could I skip the first 5 rows and replace the numbers in the index column with the subjected S001, S002,...
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I think need `df.melt('subject', var_name='cols', value_name='vals')`

Comment: Or `df.reset_index().melt('subject', var_name='cols', value_name='vals')`